# Random Quote Machine with React and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, react.js, twitter-bootstrap

For my first solo React exercise project I decided to recreate a quote machine from the example that uses vanilla JS/jQuery. I also used a mix of Bootstrap/plain CSS. I got it to look how I wanted and do what I wanted, but I am not sure if my code follows best practices. All feedback is much appreciated, as I am still quite new to web development.

I also included a link to GitHub repository, where I listed some more specific questions in the README and a React code with a commented out parts which I tried, if you are willing to help out some more:

https://github.com/Ogatron3000/Random-Quote-Machine

React:

```
React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    quotes: [],
    quote: {},
    animation: "jackInTheBox",
    colors: ["primary", "success", "warning", "danger", "info", "dark"],
    color: "primary"
  }

  // get quotes
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shreyasminocha/7d5dedafc1fe158f82563c1223855177/raw/325d51aca7165b2498971afcff9bed286a52dc0e/quotes.json")
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              quotes: res.data,
              quote: res.data[0]
            })
          })
  }

  // new quote
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      quote: this.state.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*102)],
      animation: "animated jackInTheBox",
      color:  this.state.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]
    })
  }

  render() {

    // assign random quote
    const quote = this.state.quotes.length ? (this.state.quote.quote) : ("Wait o");

    // assign author
    const author = this.state.quotes.length ? (this.state.quote.author) : ("");

    // tweet link
    const tweet = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=" 
                      + '"' + quote + '" ' + author;

    // tumblr link
    const tumblr = "https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?posttype=quote&tags=quotes,freecodecamp&caption="
                      + author + "&content=" + quote + "&canonicalUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tumblr.com%2Fbuttons&shareSource=tumblr_share_button";

    return (
      <div className={"App animted fadeIn bg-" + this.state.color}>
        <div id="quote-box" className="card">
          <p id="text" className={"text-center " + this.state.animation + " text-" + this.state.color} key={Math.random()}>
            {quote}
          </p>
          <p id="author" className={"text " + this.state.animation + " text-" + this.state.color} key={Math.random() + 1}>
            - {author}
          </p>
          <div id="buttons">
            <a id="tweet-quote" className="button-link" href={tweet} target="_blank">
              <button className={"btn btn-" + this.state.color}>
                <span className="fa fa-twitter"></span>
              </button>
            </a>
            <a id="tumblr-quote" className="button-link" href={tumblr} target="_blank">
              <button className={"btn btn-" + this.state.color}>
                <span className="fa fa-tumblr"></span>
              </button>
            </a>
            <button id="new-quote" className={"btn btn-" + this.state.color} onClick={this.handleClick}>
              New Quote
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}

.App {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: background 0.4s linear;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#quote-box{
  padding: 40px;
  width: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
}

#text{
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#author{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#buttons{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#new-quote{
  grid-column: 3 / 13;
  justify-self: end;
}

.button-link button{
  width: 40px;
}

.btn{
  transition: background 0.4s linear;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.btn:focus{
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline-style: none !important;
  color:white !important;
}

.btn:hover{
  color: white;
}
```

Thank you for your time!